# Can glassfish 3 and glassfish 4 work together on same machine but for 2 different projects

Tags: glassfish-3, glassfish-4

Glassfish 3 was installed on my machine for one java project. Now I have to set up another java project using Glassfish 4. While deploying new project's EAR, I am getting below error.

I have double check everything like domain.xml, environment variables etc. Created EAR file multiple times useing maven. But nothing worked. 
Please suggest on this. I have not deleted glassfish 3 yet. Do I need to change something on registry ?

Comment: what is your java version ?

Comment: Java version is 8

Answer (score 0):

In Glassfish 3 , Edit osgi.properties file in the glassfish/config folder and add this line at the end:

jre-1.8=${jre-1.7}

I think this will solve your issue.